# How to get average between two dates in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, average, date-difference

I'd like to get the average date between two dates in Sqlite:

In [SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19513190/2965109) is done with this simple query:

```
SELECT DateAdd(ms, DateDiff(ms, date_begin, date_end)/2, date_begin)
```

In [Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45141619/2965109):

```
SELECT date_begin + (date_end - date_begin)/2
```

Now I'd like to make the same query in Sqlite.
I try using `julianday` and convert it back to datetime:

```
SELECT date(julianday(date_begin) + (julianday(date_begin) + julianday(date_end))/2);
```

but it does not work.

Is there a simpler way to make this operation in Sqlite?

Comment: You have two `+` signs.  The second should be `-`.

Comment: You are right, it was the problem. I post the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had two `+` signs.
Here is the complete answer:

```
SELECT datetime(julianday(date_begin) + (julianday(date_end) - julianday(date_begin))/2, 'localtime');
```